# WPF Calendar Weekend Coloring

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there no simple way to coloring Weekend days? 
In ASP.Net i saw a option with the Event OnDayRender and if Weekend than set BackgroundColor. [OnDayRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.ondayrender.aspx)

But is there nothing similarly in WPF?
I saw only big solution by overriding Styles and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx) you can find a very nice tutorial on how to style a Calendar control according to your needs. Have a look at `Figure 8`, I think you can use the same technique to color Weekend values in your control.

**Update**: I've created a sample project which illustrates a solution to your issue. You can find it on [my SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=29a44a9672818421&resid=29A44A9672818421!119&parid=root): "CustomizedCalendar". Basically you need to play a little bit with the "WeekendDaysConverter".
[image: Customized calendar]

Comment: I found this solution too. But on that way you must enter every day to color. Is there no way to color ANY saturday and sunday?